# Keras classifier predict_proba() doesn't match predict()

Tags: python, classification, probability, keras, predict

I'm working with Keras Theano backend on a classification problem with 14 classes. I want the predicted class plus the associated probabilities. The problem is the probabilities from `predict_proba()` don't appear to match the predicted class from `predict()`, here is the code plus the resulting output of 1 sample.

```
PPRANK = ['pp1', 'pp2', 'pp3', 'pp4', 'pp5', 'pp6', 'pp7', 'pp8', 'pp9', 'pp10', 'pp11', 'pp12', 'pp13', 'pp14', 'pp15']

FEATURES = (PPRANK)

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("data.csv")
X = np.array(data_df[FEATURES].values)
Y = (data_df["bres"].replace(14,13).values)


# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=(len(FEATURES)), init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(14, init='normal', activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
#build model
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)

#split train and test
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1, random_state=seed)
estimator.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#get probabilities
predictions = estimator.predict_proba(X_test)

#convert expon to floats
probs = [[] for x in range(21)]
tick2 = 0
for i in range( len( predictions ) ):
    tick = 0
    for x in xrange(14):
        (predictions[i][(tick)]) = '%.4f' % (predictions[i][(tick)])
        probs[(tick2)].append((predictions[i][(tick)]))
        tick += 1
    tick2 += 1

# pprint probabilities
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=0)
pp.pprint(probs)

#print class predictions
print estimator.predict(X_test)
print Y_test
```

Result:

```
#probabilities
[0.00000, 0.00030, 0.02360, 0.04329, 0.00019, 0.00069, 0.00120, 0.00030, 0.00559, 0.00410, 0.00510, 0.91549, 0.0, 0.0]
#predicted class
11
#actual class
13
```

It shows 12 having the highest probability from `predict_proba()` rather than 11 from `predict()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index of python arrays (and here classes) counts up from 0, not from 1.  Have another look, 0.91 is the 12th value as people count things, but it's at index = 11 so `predict` and `predict_proba` are consistent.

As for why not 13, the prediction may very well be wrong (but check that you don't have the same kind of error there).